# The hline of my table is broken how to fix it

Tags: tables

I tried to create a table where the space is quite large inside each cell. However, I have got a broken line. Here is my try:

Here is my try:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \small
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline 
Note & Comments & Pages \\ [2ex] \hline

Typos & some statements  \\ &
\\
&&  34, 39, 42, 44, \\ &&
45, 51, 52, 54, \\ &&
56, 58, 71, 75,
81, 86, 91, 95,
121, 145, 146.\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was missing two `&`s. One inbetween "some statements" and the following 
`\\` and the other in the next, empty row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \small
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline 
Note  & Comments        & Pages                                         \\ [2ex] 
\hline
Typos & some statements &                                               \\ 
      &                 &                                               \\
      &                 & 34, 39, 42, 44,                               \\ 
      &                 & 45, 51, 52, 54,                               \\ 
      &                 & 56, 58, 71, 75, 81, 86, 91, 95, 121, 145, 146.\\ 
\hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Unrelated to the actual problem, but personally, I'd prefer a table without vertical lines and horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package instead. They offer a small horizontal white space around them, so they are not that close to the text as te `\hline`s are. You will also not need manually added spaces  (`[2ex]`) with this approach. Lastly, I don't really understand the need for the empty line between the "Typos"  row and the first row containing the page numbers. Also, is there a reaseon for the list of page numbers to be manually split over three rows?

---

Here is a solution using no empty lines and the `tabularx` package in order to automatically split the page numbers into two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \small
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|c|X|}
\hline 
Note  & Comments        & Pages                                         \\ [2ex] 
\hline
Typos & some statements & 34, 39, 42, 44, 45, 51, 52, 54, 56, 58, 71, 75, 81, 86, 91, 95, 121, 145, 146. \\ 
\hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is also an example of the above mentioned layout without vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \small
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llX}
\toprule
Note  & Comments        & Pages                                         \\
\midrule
Typos & some statements & 34, 39, 42, 44, 45, 51, 52, 54, 56, 58, 71, 75, 81, 86, 91, 95, 121, 145, 146. \\ 
\bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really do not want the empty line between the Typos row and the first row containing the page number. But, I do not know to fix it. For the list page numbers, I split them over three rows as the margins of the table exceed the page margin. So, my problem is I cannot fix the margin of my table.

Comment: @Mary: Would a solution that splits the page numbers automatically be fine for you? For this, please see the second example in my answer.

Comment: Amazing help. Thank you so much.